# i am not able to use in-built events in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, json

I want to book an ambulance by having conversation via google assistant so for that I am trying to get user location.

I tried to get the permission from user to access user's location using `askForPermission()`, but then that respective function is not getting called.

this is the code I wrote:

```
agent.intent('location', (conv) => {
    conv.data.requestedPermission = 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION';
    return conv.ask(new Card({
       context: 'to locate you',
       permissions: conv.data.requestedPermission,
    }));
});
```

"Webhook call failed. 500 internal server" this is the error I'm getting in response part